# Предотврощение переноса текста. flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Так должно выглядеть]

Хочу сделать width hr элемента, равную 100% свободного места. Но чтобы название было в одну строчку, без переноса, как на фото. 
И линия должна быть адаптивной при изменении длины текста

```css
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
}

.black-line {
  align-self: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  Login attempt
  <hr class="black-line">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/denchauskas/985ameyv/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается с помощью `flex-grow`. А ещё плохо использовать `hr` для визуального оформления, поэтому заменил её псевдоэлементом.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  align-self: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>Login attempt</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Учту это

Comment: @dencha  не забудьте поставить галочку если ответ Вас устраивает

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent-div {
 display: flex;
}

.black-line {
align-self: center;
border-top: 1px solid black;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.text{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent-div">
   <span class='text'>Login attempt</span>
   <hr class="black-line">
 </div>
```

Comment: Так оно не будет переноситься даже если в контейнере не хватит места под текст.

Comment: Ну это скорее просто примечание, потому что во многих случаях этот вариант вполне подходит.

Comment: У меня нет скролла. По идее дефаултный flex-shrink равен 1 и пока левый заголовок помещается, скролл не появится. А вот когда перестанет, то да.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100718/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-leks).

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо что ответили на вопросы, удачи :)